# Why does locating elements by tag name returns empty string? (Not a duplicate post)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

SO, I'm trying to get the contents of the h2 and h3 tags. Here is the code (This was inside many divs btw)

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="number">
    <h2>interest</h2>
    <h3>$1285</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <h2>Negative</h2>
    <h3>$981724</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <h2>quote</h2>
    <h3>$43342</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <h2>total</h2>
    <h3>$123456</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

And so I tried to copy xpath first:

```
container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/article/div/div/div/dl/dd[1]/div[1]')
```

I got this from selecting the div class="flex-containter.. on  the inspector and right click, find xpath.

My question is, I keep getting lost trying to find the contents of h2 and h3 because I dont know what to do with the container variable I obtained. I tried this:

```
table = container.find_elements_by_tag_name('number')
```

But it returned an empty list, I'm just guessing and checking at this point.

Can you help me find a proper documentation to better direct my attention to?
My HTML looks simple, I'm probably over complicating it. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in using selenium but I guess you must use the operation find_elements_by_class_name. There is no tag 'number' in your HTML code. I guess you are looking for the elements pointed by the class 'number'.
Check out https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I did  table = container.find_elements_by_class_name('number'). Then did a for loop for post in table: print(post.text). It printed all those h2, h3 tags.

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information